# How to hide a callback form after successful submission?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

My callback form works fine, but when client push the submit button, a 
 notification `Your request sent successfully` will appear beside buttons, and if user clicks several times on submit button then several requests are sent to the server, but what I need is when users push the submit button callback form will be hidden, and new form with `Your request sent successfully` will appear.

```
 $json = [
            'status' => 1,
            'text' => _('Your request successfully sent')
        ];
        die(json_encode($json));

    } else {

        $error = [
            'status' => 0,
            'text' => _('Write Full name and phone number')
        ];
        die(json_encode($error));

    }

}
```

ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../../engine/ajax/eogpo.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            action: 'orderCallWidget',
            phone: $('#phoneWidget').val(),
            FIO: $('#FIOWidget').val(),
            data: $('input, select').serialize()
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#overLoader").show();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status) {
                $('.product__form__error').html("");
                $("#successMessage").html(data.text);
            } else {
                $("#successMessage").html("");
                $('.product__form__error').html(data.text);
            }
            $("#overLoader").hide();
        },
        error: function() {
            $('.product__form__error').html('<?php echo _("Unknown error"); ?>');
            $("#overLoader").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: add a loader on above the button, or toggle variable to prevent form from multiple submission

Comment: Please show your frontend ajax call. You can disable your button in your "success" callback (given that you use JQuery, for example).

Comment: @Robert added ajax code

Answer (score 1):

Ok, suppose your button has the id *myButton*, just add this after `$("#overLoader").hide();`:

```
$("#myButton).attr("disabled",true);
```

You can easily adapt this to hide a div or completely remove elements from the DOM.

Comment: I added as you indicated, but nothing happened

Comment: Does your success callback fire at all? Did you check the id?

Comment: yes, callback form works fine, and my button id is #callme, i changed it, but callback form doesn't hide